# Google Cloud Functions vs. Google Cloud Functions + Pub/Sub in a Production Setting?

Tags: performance, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub, production

Is there a significant performance benefit from sending requests destined for Google Cloud Functions first through Google Pub/Sub, turning them into a queue of events/messages that the GCF can then act on, as opposed to simply sending requests directly to a GCF as, say, an HTTPS callable?

I am not familiar enough with what Google does on the back end with its Cloud Functions in order to scale them, for example, with increasing traffic, or an intense spike in traffic—for all I know GCF could be using some kind of message queue internally that I am not aware of, making the addition of an explicit Pub/Sub layer redundant.  In either case, a HTTP request still has to be made from the client to GCP, whether to create a message/event in the Pub/Sub queue or to call the GCF directly, so I just wonder if adding Pub/Sub between the client and the Cloud Function is just adding latency, and when any real performance benefits would come into play—as in, at what level of activity would such an architecture be necessary, if at all?

Basically, I have a back end for a mobile app that relies heavily on GCFs for database and Elasticsearch (hosted by GCP) search and ingestion, as well as some auth functionality, and I’m considering whether I need a messaging layer in between the client and the GCFs to support eventual production loads.

Answer (score 1):

Leaving aside all additional CAPEX (development) and OPEX (operational and support) for using PubSub as an intermediary between a caller and a cloud function, I would take into account a few other aspects as well.

The question does not describe the context and non functional requirements in details, so I have to guess a lot. From my point of view, it is not also clear what does the 'performance' mean in the question.

Anyway. A few things came to my mind.

If a caller makes a cloud function invocation, it has to wait until some answer is returned. The caller may be intelligent to make such invocation in a separate 'running flow' (however implemented), so it might not be a big deal. If not, the PubSub call might be much faster (thus lower latency) for the caller. The drawback - it the caller expect some kind of outcome/result from the cloud function invocation, that result is supposed to be delivered to the caller somehow upon the cloud function does what it supposed to do. And it might not be clear in advance, when this is going to happen, and how the result is to consumed by the caller.

The next thing from my mind - sending a message to PubSub is much more (loosely speaking) reliable than a cloud function call. Consider the cloud function call. What the caller is to do if the cloud function invocation is not successful (for any - business or infrastructure reasons)? On the other hand (delivery through the PubSub), what the cloud function is to do if the message in the PubSub cannot be handled? 'Dead letter' topics? Monitoring? Saving unhandled messages as objects in storage bucket for investigation? So, there is a lot to think about here.

If the caller is in the 'outside internet', it might not be a good idea to expose the cloud function directly anyway. Thus we might start thinking about some kind of load balancer and so on... Or may be something else. I don't' want to step into the security question here, but this topic may affect the design choices significantly.

Conclusion remarks. I think the choice is to be made taking into account a wider context and non functional requirements, rather than just a 'performance' criteria. And there is a lot to think about here.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, and sorry for the late response.  You bring up a lot of additional reasons I have been considering this change, namely logging/observability, at-least-once delivery, and message ordering.  I only ask about performance because those other benefits are obvious to me.  As it is, the cloud functions are not exposed to the 'outside internet', because they are called via httpsCallable using the JS SDK on the client, debounced, and protected server-side with a helper function that wraps all https calls with user auth token checks. (1/2)

Comment: So, in general, as long as performance would not be too adversely affected, I am definitely leaning towards replacing the direct-to-cloud-function httpsCallables with event-driven/PubSub messages, for all of those reasons.  From what I understand, it's basically as simple as creating the topic and then (in the NodeJS SDK) replacing `functions.https.onRequest` or `functions.https.onCall` with `functions.cloudEvent`, specifying the topic and transforming the message payload as necessary to carry out the original business logic, then on the client, using PubSub API instead of httpsCallable. (2/2)

Comment: Oh, and when I say "performance", I am really just specifically interested in latency and the added cost ($$) of using both PubSub and Cloud Functions.  I understand that there are other components to be considered with regard to performance, such as dead letter topics/retry policies/at-least-once delivery, etc.  I see this as a trade-off between those benefits and then potentially added cost, latency, and obviously the time needed to refactor the services that have already been built around directly calling the functions via HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays, I think Cloud Run is usually the go-to solution for serverless.
It can scale to 0 like CF can, but it can do other things more reliably as well.

Especially since Cloud Functions v2 also uses Cloud Run under the hood.